# Using JWrapper without splashscreen

Tags: java, jar, exe, jwrapper

How can I create an exe-File using `JWrapper` without getting a splash screen popped up?
Even if it just get displayed once, I don't like it.

Is this possible with the free version of `JWrapper`?

Comment: Downvote without a reason or comment is always useful.

Answer (score 0):

The free version doesn't allow you to change the splash, with the paid version you can rebrand it so that only your logo appears:

http://www.jwrapper.com/compare.html